# NEF to JPG with ImageMagick

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using ImageMagick for the first time, I've managed to get all of my dependencies installed and can run convert via Terminal, but I'm having trouble running some commands from PHP.

Here's one that has me totally stumped, this works great in terminal:

```
 convert DSC4741.nef result.jpg
```

But this won't run in PHP:

```
$im = new Imagick( 'DSC4741.nef' );
$im->setImageFormat( 'jpg' );
$im->writeImage( 'result.jpg' );
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

I can convert a jpeg no problem with PHP, but it refuses to do the .NEF.

Here's what I've checked:

- The permissions are good on the file (world writeable)
- I can convert a JPG with the exact code
- I changed the extension to lowercase
- Removed the preceding underscore from the file name

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm curious since you don't say.  What happens when you do it with the .nef  Do you get any errors?  What happens? ^^

Comment: A NEF file may be 30+MB, so you may be running into space problems. Just for a test, try setting the image size vastly smaller, say 1024x768, prior to reading it in and see if that helps... use `$im->setSize()`

Comment: @Jon I just get a blank page, and the browser console gives me a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried putting in 800x600, but it still is doing the same thing. :-(

Comment: Are you running on OS X, Linux or Windows? Are you running PHP from within Apache, or just using a stand-alone script like `#!/usr/bin/php
<?php $im=... ?>`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm running OS X Yosemite, and the PHP is running from within Apache—I've got a local site with a php page that contains only this code.

Comment: Can you wrap your code into a stand-alone shell script like I show above, and try and run that outside of Apache? Then we can rule in/out Apache as the source of the problem.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Well, Apache maybe where the problem lies, it took me a little while to learn how to and run a multiline PHP script in the terminal, but I did it using `php -a`, and it output the `result.jpg` beautifully.

Comment: Better have a look in your Apache logs for errors...

Comment: The error I'm getting seems to be pointing that I need ghostscript to run `Imagick` but I'm having trouble installing it. I'll post back when I get things sorted out.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I got ghostscript installed, but I'm still getting this error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `/var/tmp/magick-55934Og9gB9rb6P.ppm': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2675' in /Users/benowen/Sites/testing/image.php:2\nStack trace:\n#0 /Users/benowen/Sites/testing/image.php(2): Imagick->__construct('DSC4741.nef')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /Users/benowen/Sites/testing/image.php on line 2`. I can't find anything online that points to anything hopeful. :-(

Comment: I really can't imagine why you would need ghostscript to handle a `NEF` file. I'm sorry I have no more ideas to suggest, other than you try on the ImageMagick forum. Post back here and accept your own answer if you get it sorted out, please. Best of luck.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yeah, it was kind of a shot in the dark, but I found some place that said ghostscript was needed... Guess not. I'll post back hopefully!

Comment: One more idea... conversion from NEF uses the `ufraw-batch` binary/executable. Try locating that on your system and making sure it is in the PATH that PHP uses when running under Apache.

Comment: I've search around, but I can't find anything on how to add to (much less see what's in) the PATH for PHP. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are not using absolut paths.
Use something like **__FILE__** or on Windows machine (you need to replace backslash to forwardslash):

```
$im = new Imagick( str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)) . '/DSC4741.nef' );
$im->setImageFormat( 'jpg' );
$im->writeImage( str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)) . '/result.jpg' );
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

If this will not fix the problem, maybe the external programm for converting this file formates is not installed or linked in imagemagick.
See here: [Imagick is unable to open DNG images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282523/imagick-is-unable-to-open-dng-images)